# When I write my own strchr function, there is a part in the return step that I don't understand

Tags: c, return, void-pointers, char-pointer

I'm trying to write my own strchr function for school, but there is something I don't understand.

```c
char    *ft_strchr(const char *s, int c)
{
    size_t  i;
    size_t  len;

    i = -1;
    len = ft_strlen(s);
    while (++i < len + 1)
    {
        if (s[i] == (char)c)
        {
            return (((void *)&((char *)s)[i]));
        }
    }
    return (NULL);
}
```

I have completed the code's general structure and testing stages. But I couldn't understand the **return** step.

```c
return (((void *)&((char *)s)[i]));
```

Can you briefly explain to me what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line is overcomplicating things and not really best possible solution.

Let's take a closer look:

```c
char    *ft_strchr(const char *s, int c)
{
...
   return (((void *)&((char *)s)[i]));
...
}
```

First of all, `return` is not a function and therefore does not need brackets around the expression. (And there are even 2 levels of unnecessary brackets) That line is exactly the same as this one:

```c
   return (void *)&((char *)s)[i];
...
```

That line takes some value and casts it to `void*`. Casting a pointer is normally done to interpret an address as a pointer to another type than the pointer was before. Casting to `void*` is normally not needed as any pointer to a data object can automatically be converted to `void*` if needed.

But look at the function return type. It is `char*`, not `void*`. Casting the return value to `void*` does not make much sense here. Instead it should be a cast to `char*` if necessary. But the value already is of type `char*`. Therefore just drop that thing.

```c
   return &((char *)s)[i];
```

That is what you actually need. The whole point of the cast is that you have a pointer to `const char` and you need a pointer to `char`.

You could write it a bit more readable like this:

```c
   return (char *)&s[i];
```

But in the end both version will return same value with same type.

I assume with that reduced expression it is easier for you to understand what is needed in that `return` statement.